# edit html in tinymce does not convert \n to line breaks

Tags: tinymce

When i set the content to 'a\nb' in tinymce, the edit in html shows 'ab', and when i set it again, through console. it shows as

```
a
b
```

why could this be happening? and how to fix it?

Comment: Here is a late solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104384/tinymce-remove-text-spaces-and-line-breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of of the cleanup functionality of tinymce. Using html will yield html without tinymce internal elements/attributs and cleaned content.

Comment: what happens if you set it and click on each paragraph in your content?