# (Tinymce) Line breaks get stripped off in firefox while using getContent{format:text}

Tags: tinymce

I was trying to type the few lines in firefox and expect to use getContent{format: text} to only fetch the content.

```
 Here is the content: (I have three lines and each start with the leftmost postion)
 "text me if
 there is
 a chance"

 It works in chrome that it gives the following format when running getContent.
 ...
 <body>
 text me if

 there is

 a chance
 </body>
 ...

 However in firefox I got:

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  text me ifthere isa chance
  </body>
  </html>

 It seems to strip off the line break. Could someone help on this?
```

Answer (score 3):

In TinyMCE 4+ there is no option to disable stripping off line breaks. For me a littly dirty hack worked - just replace line breaks with `<br>` tags before initializing TinyMCE:

```
//imagine that your textarea is called textarea#message
var a = $("textarea#message").val();
a = a.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
$("textarea#message").val(a);
```

If you need afterwards text without `<br>` but with line breaks, just apply the same transformation vise versa:

```
var a = $("textarea#message").val();
a = a.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
$("textarea#message").val(a);
```

Comment: I wonder is there a convenient way to excute these two javascript codes before and after I pass the text to TinyMCE?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but it just happened to me to walk into the same problem. It seems firefox has some issues with linebreaks in text that gets inserted into a textarea. My solution was something like this:

```
var text = text.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n");
```

I guess FireFox is just a great fan of Slash(es)...

For the full solution I used the following code, which does not use the format: text, but format: html which get parsed by the DOMParser first:

```
var text = editor.getContent({ format: 'html' });
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
text = doc.body.textContent.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n");
```

In case you still want to have  tags within the code to display aswell as the link as the text within the tag add this line before the DOMParser:

```
    text = text.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, ' $2: $1 ');
```

Which will change:

- [Go to some page](//some.link)

to this:

- Go to some page: //some.link

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure things like this don't happen you should use a `<br>` tag instead of a regular line brea (ctrl+return). This is the default procedure in html code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate a little bit more. My goal is the extract the words from tinymce with no format. That is why I am using getContent{format:ｔｅｘｔ}．　(I am developing the spell check outside of tinymce).You are suggesting to use<br> as tag. How to set it in tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by using DOMParser().

```
    tinymceContextValue = tinymce.get('abstract1').getContent({format: 'html'});  
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(tinymceContextValue ,'text/html');
    tinymceContextValue  = doc.body.textContent;
```

In this case, we could still preserve the line break. But be noted that do not change the tinymce configuration to enable 
. It will not work with it.