# TinyMCE strips out all line breaks on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, tinymce

I have some html-encoded text in `TinyMCE v3.5.10`, say `This is a <br/>market`.

I am trying to extract the html as well as the plain text equivalent of the above line. On IE, Firefox and Chrome, the above line is rendered as:

```
This is a 
market
```

and this is the same as the plain text content extracted using: `tinyMCE.get('inputText').getContent({format: 'text'});`

On Firefox though, the line breaks are stripped out and what I get is: `This is a market.`, not all what I was expecting.

My init for tinyMCE:

```
 tinymce.init({

                 selector: "textarea",

                 plugins : "contextmenu", //,mainMenuBar",//,goToPage", 

                 mode : "textareas",
                 theme : "advanced",
                 editor_deselector: "mceNoEditor",
                 theme_advanced_layout_manager : "SimpleLayout",
                 //toolbar : false,
                 //menubar : false,    //removes the top menu bar.

                 //layout items.
                 theme_advanced_buttons1 : "",
                 theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                 theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                 //theme_advanced_toolbar : false,
                 theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "external",
                 theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

                 statusbar : false,
                 theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "external",
                 theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                 theme_advanced_path : false,

                 //theme_advanced_buttons1 : "openFile,|,chooseVoice,setReadingMode,setReadingSpeed,|,lookupDictionary,translate,pictureDictionary,|,settings,|,logout",
                 //theme_advanced_buttons1 : "backToLibrary,|,play,setReadingSpeed,|,lookupDictionary,translate,pictureDictionary,|,pronounce,|,settings,|,moreOptions",
                 //paste_text_sticky: false,
                 //paste_text_sticky_default: false,
                 nowrap : false,
                 button_tile_map : true,
                 entity_encoding : "raw",
                 force_br_newlines : true,
                 forced_root_block : "", // Needed for 3.x
                 //valid_elements : "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,br,span[class|title|onmouseover|onmouseout|onclick|style],div[style],img[src|width|height|alt],hr,i",
                 event_elements : "span",

                 /*
                 paste_text_sticky : true,
                 pasteAsPlainText : true,
                 paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
                 paste_remove_styles: true,
                 paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
                 paste_strip_class_attributes: true,
                 */

                 setup: function(editor) {
                    editor.onInit.add(function(editor) {
                                   editor.pasteAsPlainText = true;                                   
                                   //call function to create custom context (right-click) menu.
                                   console.log("creating custom context menu.");
                                   editor.plugins.contextmenu.onContextMenu.add(createCustomContextMenu);

                                   //create bottom status bar for going to page number.
                                   //goToPagePlugin();
                    });
                 }
    });
```

As you can see, I thought this might be because of the `paste_as_plain_text` being set to true, but even commenting it out does not seem to have had any effect.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Here are the answers for 3 and 4 version of TinyMCE:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104384/tinymce-remove-text-spaces-and-line-breaks