# Preserving line breaks in TinyMCE source editor

Tags: wordpress, formatting, tinymce

First off, this question has been asked in many forms across the internets but I still haven't found a solution or a definite "not possible" answer.

I'm wondering if I can preserve line breaks in the TinyMCE source editor, Wordpress 4.1.

I currently have the plugin TinyMCE Advanced activated, with the option `"Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the Text editor"` enabled.

Here are paragraphs that I separated by line breaks. This is how I'd like the text to be preserved:

[image]

I then hit 'OK' and re-open the source editor. Here's what's displayed:

[image]

At this point, I activate the plugin TinyMCE Advanced, and enable the option `"Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the Text editor"`. This option half-way solves my problem by linebreaking on tags:

[image]

However, I still would like a line break between the paragraphs like in the first photo. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: If it is TinyMCE fault then this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104384/tinymce-remove-text-spaces-and-line-breaks